# Unable to translate bytes [FC] at index 35 from specified code page to Unicode

Tags: asp.net, .net, unicode, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to send an object like this to my REST API(built with asp net core)

```
{
    "firstName":"tersü",
    "lastName":"asda"
}
```

And this is how the headers form SoapUI look:

```
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json:charset=UTF-16
Host: localhost:4004
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

However, my `actionContext.ModelState` is always invalid because it can not work with the umlaute. The exception is the following:

> Unable to translate bytes [FC] at index 35 from specified code page to
>   Unicode

If it's any help, the method signature looks like this:

```
[ValidateUserData]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string userId, [FromBody] UpdateUserRequest updateRequest)
```

Basically the code never goes over

```
if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(actionContext.ModelState);
}
```

inside the `[ValidateUserData]` attribute

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are sending your string encoded in `utf-16`, but telling (in the `Content-Type` header's charset) it is `utf-8`.

The bytes for `tersü` in `utf-8` are:

```
74,65,72,73,C3,BC
```

However `tersü` (in `utf-16`) contains the bytes (notice the `FC` there):

```
74,0,65,0,72,0,73,0,FC,0
```

(Check it [in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zmD0fG))

So it just can't understand it. So either convert your string to `utf-8` in your client before sending it, or set the `Content-Type` charset to `utf-16` .

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a mistake on my part. The headers i pasted are the response header, not the request ones. i've updated with request headers

Answer (score 2):

Although the Content-Type is charset UTF-8 the received byte code FC denotes the extended ASCII character 252 which represents the umlaut "ü".

In a UTF-8 encoding the umlaut "ü" consists of two bytes. So there is a mismatch between the given encoding header and the transmitted data. So you have to check the code which generates the request.

Comment: The fact that the index is 35, makes it much more bearable that the content being sent is actually utf-16 (not extended ascii)... and actually, extended ASCII's byte 252 (FC) is ³, not ü *(ü is 129 [hex 81])*

Comment: @Jcl: I took the information about the FC hex code to character mapping from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#/media/File:Table_ascii_extended.png and ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-1.TXT. But  where is the information what bytes are going over the wire in the environment of the OP ?

Comment: actually, extended ascii depends on the codepage, so it's possible that we both are right :-) About the information, I'm just making that assumption since the error says at index 35... depends a bit on newlines and spaces that might be in the question and not in the actual data, but I'd say index 35 sounds like right for utf-16 and the presented data. I could definitely be wrong, but sounds like a safe assumption (plus: in .NET strings are encoded in utf-16 by default, and the OP is not mentioning anything else)

Comment: @Jcl  ok I see. Thanks for sharing your thoughts and assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution to the question asked - but a solution for a related problem:

I was having this error message when downgrading a Winforms application from Net.4.0 to Net.2.0 (because of 3rd party form control issues)

Every instance of an ImageList object that was specified in the forms designer was affected.

I cut all such instances out of the RESX file and out of the Designer code, made them private objects, and did the required initialization in the Form_Load event.

No problems since then in Net.2.0 or Net 4.0 configurations.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this error when working with SSRS on a .rdl file. The solution was that I needed to save the file as an unsigned UTF-8 file rather than a signed UTF-8 file. Here is how you do that in Visual Studio:

1. Open your XML code by going to View -> Code, or pressing F7
2. While viewing your XML code page, select File -> Advanced Save Options
3. In the resulting pop-up windows select, "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)..."
4. Click OK

That fixed the problem for me, I hope it helps!

Comment: This solution does not relate to what OP asked.