# Strange response from Asp.Net Web Api Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Asp.Net Web Api like the following

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Guid id, OrganisationModel model)
{
    try
    {       
        _orgService.AddNewOrganisationToParent(newOrg, org);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(newOrg.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat("Problem creating new organisation {0}. Error {1}", UserId, ex);
        return InternalServerError(ex);
   }
}
```

When I call this from another Asp.Net Web application with the following;

```
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var newOrg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                name = systemTree.Name,
                type = 0
            });

            var content = new StringContent(newOrg.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");           
            var newOrgId = Guid.Empty;

            using (var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(orgEndpoint + orgId, content))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                newOrgId = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Guid>().Result;
            }
```

The response is rather strange, the code shown throws and exception "exceptionMessage": "Unable to translate bytes [B4] at index 3 from specified code page to Unicode.",

If I read this as a string I get the following

"SJN4OMN4��MIK2�M574Ե0H6�500H1NL2J�4IR\u0002\0"

Is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to translate bytes \[FC\] at index 35 from specified code page to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076157/unable-to-translate-bytes-fc-at-index-35-from-specified-code-page-to-unicode)

Comment: Different issue, but you should not block by using `.Result`.

Comment: @Crowcoder Cheers, I did have this as an await but have been trying every possible alternative to fix the issue

Comment: Are you sure your server is configured to use UTF-8 for Responses?

Comment: Hi @spodger How would I go about checking this? I am using IIS

Comment: Using IIS Manager (8.5 - should be similar for earlier versions), select the site then on the right hand side double click .NET Globalization under ASP.NET.

Comment: Yep Requests, Response Headers and Responses are set to utf-8