# How to pass accents characters to REST APIs in post methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, soapui

I need to pass my request body to a post method of Web API and in request body have some special characters like ã

Below is the request body :

```
{
  "query": "den",
  "city": "São Paulo",
  "country": "Brazil",
  "location": null
}
```

> Error : "Unable to translate bytes [E3] at index 32 from specified
>   code page to Unicode."

Anybody has any solution I tried `application/json;charset=utf-16` and `application/json;charset=utf-8`

Also while debugging the code parameter value is coming null.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076157/unable-to-translate-bytes-fc-at-index-35-from-specified-code-page-to-unicode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to translate bytes \[FC\] at index 35 from specified code page to Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076157/unable-to-translate-bytes-fc-at-index-35-from-specified-code-page-to-unicode)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and I resolved it by adding

```
(consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

with your `postMapping`.